# Text and icon position in flex alert

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, styles, alert

How can I change the position of the text and the icon in flex alert? It is on the top of the Alertbox, but it should be horizontally centered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `mx|Alert
        {
            vertical-align:middle;
            text-align:center;
        }`